# how to copy nk.bin to partition on wince 6.0

Tags: windows-ce

i want to copy nk.bin to partition on wince 6.0.
i want that when i restart device then using redboot cammand it should be able to load nk.bin from partion. how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a broad and pretty platform-specific question.  Forst, you've not told us much about your platform, so we have to make assumptions.  I'll assume, based on you using redboot and talking about "partitions" that you'r running on ARM and that your OS image is stored in persistent storage (i.e. Flash).

The next question is "How and where is the OS stored?"  This is platform specific, so only you (or your OEM) can say.  It might be inside a FAT 32 volume or it might be written raw to a specific location in flash outside of any file system.  If it's the former (it's probably not, or you likely wouldn't be asking the question), you could copy it.  If it's just at some location raw, you're going to need APIs to directly access the flash.  See if the OEM provided them (apps can't map direct to hardware in 6.0, so if there's no OEM-provided API, you'll have to write a driver).

You also need to know if you're XIP.  If so, I don't think you're going to be able to copy the OS while it's running - at least I'd consider it a high-risk operation.  In that case you likely need to set some sort of bit somewhere outside the existing file system (an EEPROM, scratch-pad regiter, raw flash, etc) and reboot, then modify the bootloader to make the copy.

THis all assumes you mean you want to copy it from on the device itself.  You could mean you want to copy it using a JTAG tool as well, in which case everything I've said is irrelevant (except the location of the OS - and even that's not relevant if you're thinking you want to copy it from an outside source).